# More streamlined way to write this if statement in cshtml

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I just wanted to see if there is a more streamlined way to write this `if` statement below?

```
                    @if (templateGroupTitle != null)
                    {
                        var templateTitleCourse = @templateTitle + " - " + @templateGroupTitle;
                        <td><a href="Template comparisons/@(templateId).html">@templateTitleCourse</a></td>

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td><a href="Template comparisons/@(templateId).html">@templateTitle</a></td>
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, something like this:

```
<td><a href="Template comparisons/@(templateId).html">@(templateTitle + (templateGroupTitle != null ? (" - " + templateGroupTitle) : ""))</a></td>
```

Or maybe even better

```
@
{
    var title = templateTitle + (templateGroupTitle != null ? (" - " + templateGroupTitle) : "");
}

<td><a href="Template comparisons/@(templateId).html">@title</a></td>
```

And maybe the best:

```
@
{
    var delimiter = " - ";
    var title = string.Join(delimiter, templateTitle, templateGroupTitle).TrimEnd(delimiter.ToCharArray());
    // var title = $"{templateTitle}{delimiter}{templateGroupTitle}".TrimEnd(delimiter.ToCharArray()); // Another way
}

<td><a href="Template comparisons/@(templateId).html">@title</a></td>
```

Choose which method do you prefer the most.

I might be confused with brackets, but you got the idea.